# Spline interpolation in Excel

Tags: excel-2007

I'll make this clear and simple, since I'm on a deadline here. Doing some reports for my section, and I came to a part where I could really use an interpolation in Excel.

Now, I've never had any practice with its functions, or VBA in general. So, is there a place where I could, or do anyone of you guys know some, ... where I could pick up a simple spline interpolation along with a tutorial of "how to make it work" (literally, I have no idea - I use Excel on a one-handful-of-times-on-an-annual-basis)?

I just need something that will put up a spline (or something similar) on an x and y column of values, and give me the interpolated result given values of X.

p.s. I know however of trendlines, but they're no use for me in this case. I cannot get the coefficients "programmatically" ...

I'd really appreciate some pragmatical help.

Comment: FWIW you _can_ get the co-efficients of a trend line programatically.  See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/255149/67240) for an example

Answer (score 4):

http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/excel-interpolate-cubic-curve-fit.htm

`XlXtrFun.xll` is what I use to get splines in Excel.

Comment: download link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 4):

This is a free add-in for Excel that adds spline and linear interpolation workbook functions:

http://www.srs1software.com/SRS1CubicSplineForExcel.aspx

Comment: While the site lists previous versions of the add-in, I can find no download links for these.  I was looking for a cubic spline that would run on Excel 2003, and while their oldest release (v1.03) is listed as running on "almost any version" of Excel I can't find any links.  Annoyingly, the formatting of the headers before each paragraph is blue text, underlined, but they ain't links.  ; - (